# How can I navigate from a cshtml page to a webform?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have created a mvc project but found I need to add a webforms page. I have tired a few variations of this but have only gotten 404 errors. Seen a few suggestions elsewhere and settled on this:

```
function ViewRunSheet() {
    var route = document.getElementById('Route').value;
    var routeDate = $("#RouteDate").find("input").val();

    window.location.href = "./RunSheet.aspx?route=" + route + "&date=" + moment(routeDate).format('YYYYMMDD');
}
```

Has anyone got any ideas as to:

1. Why this method doesn't appear to work
2. If there is a better solution I should be using

Also its my first question so if I have missed anything major I will edit it in

**EDIT** This is Running locally on my system and is not deployed via IIS

**EDIT** Since posting I have been playing around and decided to test moving the web form out of my views folder directly into the root folder and now the code works. This is good however I am intrigued to know why if anyone knows

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add below in route.config file to ignore the routing for aspx page

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: Thanks unfortunately this still doesn't seem to work I receive the following error:

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: /Warehouse/RunSheet.aspx

Comment: ASPX path is correct one? Means please check if you have deployed on IIS then it comes with the proper website path... or if the page is within any folder then the whole path is coming in URL correctly... It's possible that sometimes we did small mistakes.

Comment: Have you added the aspx page in MVC application or in existing aspx web form application you have added the MVC?

Comment: My path is:
Views/Warehouse/RunSheet.aspx 
so the ./Warehouse should be fine. I did try using ~/Views/etc but that had an issue where the URL was coming out as: http://localhost:49964/Warehouse/~/Views/Warehouse/RunSheet.aspx?route=TEST&date=20180812

I also realised I should have specified that this was running locally and not deployed on IIS

Comment: I added the aspx into an MVC application

Comment: Can you please try directly:  localhost:49964/Views/Warehouse/RunSheet.aspx

Does it work?

Comment: I received the same error again doing this, could I be missing references that wouldn't be present in an MVC application that WebForms would require?